# Outgoing donations tracking

Tags: civicontribute, wordpress, activities, contributions

I've installed CiviCRM on my non-profit organization (Wordpress 4.2.2, CiviCRM 4.6.3, MySql 5.1 and PHP 5.3), a trashware association which get computers from companies, other association and families and donate them to people who cannot purchase a computer.

Do you know if there are modules / extension which can allow us to track the outgoing donations too?

I can see that with CiviContribute it's possible to track donations, but it's not applicable to our needs, is that correct? If I well looked at it, it shouldn't be possible to track the donation of computers to us, only moneys...right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

For incoming donations, CiviContribute does have the ability to track "in kind" non-monetary donations. Visit **Administer > CiviContribute > Payment Instruments** and add "In kind" as an option.

You can also set up some custom fields to extend the contribution record with options like e.g. "hardware type", etc.

Answer (score 2):

You might have good luck with CiviGrant, which is built into Core:

http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/grants/what-is-civigrant/